# How to insert multiline in the JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to insert some code in JSX;

**Use props of value:**

Child:

```
<Child value="
var s = 'hello';
console.log(s);
" />
```

Parent:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.props.value}>
```

But there is no line break;

**Use children:**

Child:

```
<Child>
var s = 'hello';
console.log(s);
<Child/>
```

result:compile error

How to solve this problem?

Comment: So you checked the answer that is basically exact copy paste of mine but with silly picture of a keyboard?

Comment: Why you said sguetsch's answer is copy of your answer? Maybe he/she just have the same solution?

Comment: Because my answer was 7 minutes earlier. So they put identical answer 7 minutes after my already was there. It's sad that you encourage copy-paste answers. I went through their profile and found multiple answers when they answer after another people with *identical code*. So, that's how it looks like.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the backtick enclosed template string literals:

```
<Child value={`
var s = 'hello';
console.log(s);
`} />
```

References:

- [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)